# Error in select option jquery 2.1.1 in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, html-select, attr

I have a problem with jquery version 2.1.1 and 2.2.2

I have a select like this

```
 <select id="test">
     <option value="10">10</option>
     <option value="20" selected="selected">20</option>
     <option value="30">30</option>
     <option value="40">40</option>
</select>
```

and when I try with chrome Versión  49.0.262

```
$('#test option[value="30"]').attr("selected","selected");
```

and after that

```
$('#test option:selected');
```

return this:

```
'<option value="20" selected="selected">20</option>'
```

but in the Versión 37.0.2062.94 (64-bit) of chrome 
return this

```
'<option value="30">30</option>'
```

I tried it in javascript console  from the two versions.
Please anyone has any idea of the problem.

I have the same problem in firefox 45.0

regards

Comment: If you want select value=30 ... `$('#test').val('30'); `

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.prop('selected', true);` http://api.jquery.com/prop/